# How to fetch the last table record related to scope? Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to bring only the POST without comments and if they have comments only bring me if the last comment is contact_type_id=4, the issue I manage to bring me the list of products with or without comments, but I can not make me also make the filter that if the last comment is with ID 4 show it to me, so it chooses to bring me all the data.

How could I solve it, since after that query I make more scope that filter more things of the Product.

**Controller**

```
$leads = Lead::openedStage1()->doesntCommentOrHasComments($filter_id);
```

**Model**

```
public function scopeOpenedStage1($query){
    $query
        ->where('status_id','!=',5)->where('status_id','!=',4);
}

public function scopeDoesntCommentOrHasComments($query,$filter_id){
        if ($filter_id == 1 )
            $query->doesntHave('comments')->orWhereHas('comments', function($q){
                $q->where('contact_type_id','=',4)->orderBy('date_publication','DESC');//not worked latest
            });

        if ($filter_id == 2)
            $query->doesntHave('comments')->orWhereHas('comments', function ($q){
                $q->where('contact_type_id','!=',4);
            });
            
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: Can you simply apply a `->limit(1)` to your query? It would allow you to continue chaining methods, but doesn't return anything like `->first()` does.

Comment: @TimLewis I think that will not work as he is looking to get the last comment (if it has one) that is `contact_type_id = 4`, if it is different than `4` do not get it, so `limit(1)` will always get the last one ignoring `contact_type_id`.

Comment: Author, I am not skilled with those sort of queries (if you can make it in one query), but I can tell you that avoid using harcoded references to your code. For example, do not use `5` or `4` as `status_id`s in your code, make them constants in the correct class and reference that constant, so if one day changes, it will change everywhere to the same value and also it is trackable (by a the IDE). Same for `contact_type_id` or any `enum` you want to use in PHP. My humble recommendation.